# Retrieving object by ID using map

Tags: java, dictionary

Hi i Was looking for method to retrieve ArrayList object by object's ID, some guy in topic from 2013 told that you should use Map to do this. But how can i use Object ID as a Map key?

```
   Map<Item.getId(),Item> items = new TreeMap<>();
```

Comment: use like this `Map<Integer,Item> items = new TreeMap<>();` and please provide some sample code

Comment: @AshokKumarN my whole code Was using ArrayList :D I want to change everything to use Map but i couldn't figure this

Comment: What is an `ID` type? `Integer`, `String`, something else?

Comment: @MichałZiober int

Comment: @Sharkmen please post the code or snippet, be descriptive to understand

Comment: @AshokKumarN but there is no code to show here, everything Was using ArrayList. I got class Item with name, id and some other fields and i wanted to change everything from ArrayList to Map

Comment: please follow oleg.cherednik his answer make id as key and pojo as value

Answer (score 1):

```
class Item {
    // id could be any type you like. Mostly this is simple types: int, long, String, UUID
    private final int id;
    // ... other fields
}

Map<Integer, Item> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(666, new Item(666));
Item item = map.get(666);  // get an item with id=666;
```

**P.S.** Additionally, make sure that you realize how `hashCode()` and `equals()` work.